# Dependency Injection vs Static

Tags: php, symfony, code-injection

I am learning symfony framework and I am wondering : 
if I need something like an helper (for example) is it better to make a service (to do a dependancy injection into my controller) or is it better to create a static function.
What are the pros and cons of each method.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very significant question regarding the best way to add reusable libraries that does very specific processes.

The Symfony way is make it a service and register it in the service container.

```
<?php 

namespace Acme\MainBundle\Services;

class MobileHelper
{
    public function formatMobile($number)
    {
        $ddd = substr($number, 0, 2);
        $prefix_end_index = strlen($number) == 11 ? 5 : 4;
        $prefix = substr($number, 2, $prefix_end_index);
        $suffix = substr($number, -4, 4);

        return sprintf('(%s) %s-%s', $ddd, $prefix, $suffix);
    }

    public function unformatMobile($number)
    {
        $number = preg_replace('/[()-\s]/', '', $number);

        return $number;
    }
}
```

Then on services.yml

```
  mobile.helper:
    class: Acme\MainBundle\Services\MobileHelper
```

Then you can use it in your controller like:

```
$mobileHelper = $this->get('mobile.helper');
$formattedMobile = $mobileHelper->formatMobile('11999762020');
```

Comment: Ok it seems clear to me :) 
But is there any explanation of why service (like you did at the top) is better than static class which contains static method.
These methods will then be call like `MobileHelper::formatMobile('11999762020')` in our controller.

Comment: @hornfl4kes By using a static class you are tightly coupling it in your controller, whereas by using DI, you could typehint an interface and not worry about a specific implementation in the controller. Please note that the above code strictly is not dependency injection, but using a service locator.

Comment: @hornfl4kes In this example, there wasn't a reason to inject the service container or the entity manager in the service, but when you need to access another service or even the entity manager it's way better to inject them on the constructor than having a set of symfony kernel calls to load other dependencies.. check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 1):

Static functions in Controllers doesn't seem like a very Symfony way of doing things. Services and dependancy injection tend to be the way to go as it at once decouples the functionality from a single controller AND makes it more easily reusable. Think this method will probably also sharpen your logic regarding how you build that service. Symfony best practise is for light controllers, so any heavy business logic should be moved out to a service.